# Blocking main thread only on last loop to allow file upload to finish

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a main UI that has long processing tasks. I update a few hundred databases with information from a web server. The databases are stored in a repository where they need to be downloaded, then updated, then uploaded (checked back in) to the repository.

I am not so concerned with the length of work, but I have implemented a Background worker thread to handle the upload so that the next file can start processing. Each step of the process is logged to a couple of different XML log files for later analysis on what was updated in each file. Works great until...

My issue is that just before I loop I call the run Async background worker to handle the upload, works great until the last file. I have tried a dozen or more different techniques to block, IsBusy, join, sleep, etc. the main thread, in order to wait for only the last file to be uploaded before I can close up my XML writers, and confirm that all files were uploaded correctly.

I have also tried to implement the RunWorkerCompleted which fires okay, but only after returning to the main thread, so even if I set a flag or add logic to the last condition of the event, I get an "in use" error on my XML writer. Can't figure that one out either since I would have thought it was done updating.

I can post any code needed. Its a bit of spaghetti at this point, I guess I could use some help, direction, examples, of how to block the main thread on the last record of my loop only, so I can allow the final upload to finish. I really do not like just adding a Sleep as it just seems too inefficient and doesn't really respond when actual processing has completed.

vb.net

Main UI

```
For 
  '  Processing ....

        returnFiletoSS()

        fileCountChker = fileCountChker + 1
Next

myXmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement()
myXmlTextWriter.Close()

myXmlTextWriter1.WriteEndElement()
myXmlTextWriter1.Close()

objWriter.Close()


    '  Prior test logic
    ' ''If fileCountChker = numOfFiles Then
    ' ''    While TestWorker.IsBusy
    ' ''        Threading.Thread.Sleep(400)
    ' ''    End While
```

this fires before TestWorker_RunWorkerCompleted

```
    If lastRecord Then
        objWriter1.Close()
    Else

        While lastRecord <> True
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(400)
        End While
        objWriter1.Close()
    End If
```

calls this function...

```
Private Sub returnFiletoSS()

    ' This Background worker Process .
    TestWorker = New BackgroundWorker

    TestWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    TestWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    TestWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub


    ' This event handler deals with the results of the background operation.
Private Sub TestWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles TestWorker.RunWorkerCompleted

    ' First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
    If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
    ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
     ' Next, handle the case where the user canceled the operation.
     ' Note that due to a race condition in the DoWork event handler,
     ' the Cancelled flag may not have been set, even though
     ' CancelAsync was called.
        Form2.resultLabel("Canceled")
    Else
     ' Finally, handle the case where the operation succeeded.
     '    Form2.resultLabel(e.Result.ToString())

        lastRecord = True
     '  objWriter1.Close()  'Tried closing writer here, but errors.
    End If
```

Comment: You will have to unpick your spaghetti and post some code for us to have a hope of solving this. During your unpicking process you might find your issue. That's why spaghetti code is bad ;-)

Comment: Sure, it wasn't spaghetti when I started, just trying to solve this thread issue. Stand by.,

Comment: Are you trying to upload each file in parallel?

Comment: They may, if the next one processes faster than the prior takes to upload. But that is not a requirement. I just send each off to get uploaded when it is done being processed. I doubt that there ever will be one that is not uploaded by the time the next is ready to get uploaded.

Comment: I could think of many ways to do it: with Async/Await, Action.BeginInvoke/callback, Thread.Start()/Join(). Backgroundworker is good for when you want to update the UI in a built-in way, but any of the other solutions would work as well. Keeping your code as is, maybe you should look into putting a `SyncLock` around the XML writer?

Comment: Not sure how to use syncLock on Background worker

Comment: Is there some way to pass objWriter1 into the RunWorkerCompleted Event?

Comment: Okay so I read up on SyncLock, but don't see a technique for locking the last loop and waiting for the last Async to complete. Where would the End Sync Lock need to go? Inside RunWorkerCompleted Event?

Comment: The SyncLock never knows if there is a pending write to the XML. If I lock the objWriter1, I don't know when to unlock it until RunWorkerCompleted Event completes, but I can't seem to get back to calling thread when that event fires.

Comment: That's not quite how it works. Like this: `SyncLock someObject` `' write to the file` `End SyncLock`. It makes it so that only one thread can be doing `'write to the file` at a time. The object used `someObject` can be any object i.e. `Private someObject = new Object()`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx

Comment: I placed the SyncLock around the entire DoWork, TestWorker.RunWorkerAsync() process and it still failed. the Object writer is getting closed before the Async process can log the results of the upload.

Comment: @Verdolino I have concluded that the SyncLock will not work. The upload finishes and closes the XML, I need to stop that from happening until the last file completes updating. Even with the Lock the process is fast enough that it unlocks then closes the writer before the last file is done.